# How can I send a message to an Outlook group?

Tags: outlook.com

I want to send a group email from my Outlook.com account, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to [create a contact group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/create-a-contact-group-HA102919788.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102919798):

Go to People, under My Contacts, pick where you want to add the contact group, say Contacts.
Click Home > New Contact Group and in the Contact Group tab, in the Name box, type a name for the group.
Click Add Members, and then add people from your address book or contacts list.

To [send an email message to a contact group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/send-an-email-message-to-a-contact-group-HA102919798.aspx):

Home > New Email, in the new email message, click To, Select the address book, in the Search box, type the name of the contact group, double-click the name to add it to the To box, and then click OK.